# Macro button for +1 water consumed to match =Today()

Tags: excel, function

I am in process of completing a food journal and I track it in Excel. I like to update live (vs. end of day) and every time I have a glass of water, I would like to press the macro button and it finds today's date and adds +1 to it on a running tally.

Is there a way to do a Match Function to find today's date in cell A4 with a formula in A4 as:
=Today()  and match it with my food journal dates (dates are in Column B)?

Trying to Match today's date with A4 and the number will increase the number of water glass consumed by 1 each time. I am familiar with MATCH and INDEX as formulas but can't figure it out in VBA.

All I have now is the add 1 to cell

```
Cells(1,1).Value = Cells(1,1).Value + 1
```

I would like to get a cumulative number by pressing a macro button x number of times to give me total water glass consumption for today.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best way to do this with VBA is to use the Range.Find method. Here is the documentation for using it correctly, as well as how you can handle not finding the value you are looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

The Range.Find method returns a range object, which is basically a cell address. You could offset that address by one column to update the value in Column B. Your `Cells(1,1).Value = Cells(1,1).Value + 1` should work just fine for that. Let me know if you have any questions! Good Luck!